# How to rotate block in matlab?

Tags: matlab, rotation, block, cell, fingerprint

Without use of Image processing toolbox to divide the image, I used cell array. If I want to rotate each block I should develope imrotate, but how? working with cell is not easy. Here is my code for division:

```
A= double(imread('cameraman.tif'));

blockSize = [5 5]

  m = 1;
blocks = floor(size(A)./blockSize);
div_im = cell(blocks);

for j = 1:blocks(2)
    for i = 1:blocks(1)

        % The indices to the current block
        blockIndsX = (1:blockSize(1)) + (i-1)*blockSize(1);
        blockIndsY = (1:blockSize(2)) + (j-1)*blockSize(2);

        div_im{m} = A(blockIndsX, blockIndsY, :);

        m = m + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: So you are actually asking how to find the angle between ridges and the x-axis? You should probably edit your question title. Also please provide a sample image.

Comment: No, I have measured the local angle at each block. But dont know how to rotate that its final angle to x-axis be 90

Comment: Then let's see some code for your attempts

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should  clear before asking what to ask..and as far as your image rotation is concerned this code might help you..If i am wrong at understanding your question please bring it to my notice..

here image is divided into blocks of 50*50..

```
im = double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
[m,n] = size(im);
% deg = block angle+90; to rotate anticlockwise
% deg = block angle*90; to rotate clockwise
% rotating clockwise will title your x axis to 90 deg..
% divide it in a block of 50*50
for i = 1:50:m-50
    for j = 1:50:n-50
        blk_im = im(i:i+49,j:j+49);
        rot_im(i:i+49,j:j+49) = imrotate(blk_im,deg,'bilinear','crop');

    end;
end;
imshow(rot_im,[]);
```

here the block angle should be in degrees..if its in radian than convert it to degree using `radtodeg` function..

Answer (score 0):

Use rotation matrix

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

http://in.mathworks.com/help/phased/ref/rotx.html

[Calculating a rotation matrix using rotate in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461150/calculating-a-rotation-matrix-using-rotate-in-matlab)